# Unit tests take a long time to run. Valgrind problem? Gcov problem?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, valgrind, gcov

I've created a unit test suite for a project I'm working on. My unit tests used to run very quickly... 200+ of them would run within a few seconds. Typically each test would take less than 10 milliseconds. Now while using Valgrind and Gcov each test can take over 1.5 minutes to run! Has anyone had any experience with very slow unit tests? Does Valgrind, gcov, or Google Test cause significant slowdown of program execution in any particular situations? What's even more confusing is that some of the unit test run just fine (i.e. very quickly) while others take many seconds to run. And often, when running the unit tests again, the same tests take a different amount of time to run. I'm basically trying to figure out where the bottleneck is. Below is an example:

```
[ RUN      ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.TerminalsOnly
[       OK ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.TerminalsOnly (34 ms)
[ RUN      ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AlohaAndTerminals
[       OK ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AlohaAndTerminals (38 ms)
[ RUN      ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocatePeriodic
[       OK ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocatePeriodic (304 ms)
[ RUN      ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocatePeriodic_Disabled
[       OK ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocatePeriodic_Disabled (152 ms)
[ RUN      ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocateFair
[       OK ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocateFair (109 ms)
[ RUN      ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocateFair_Disabled
[       OK ] BandwidthAlgorithmTest.AllocateFair_Disabled (64 ms)
[----------] 12 tests from BandwidthAlgorithmTest (2763 ms total)

[----------] 7 tests from BacklogHelperTest
[ RUN      ] BacklogHelperTest.ChangeInrouteState
[       OK ] BacklogHelperTest.ChangeInrouteState (80613 ms)
[ RUN      ] BacklogHelperTest.GetInvalidInroute
[       OK ] BacklogHelperTest.GetInvalidInroute (98471 ms)
```

Comment: Ofcourse, programs run slower with valgrind, it does the work of trying to figure out programs dirt.

Comment: Valgrind adds a ton of overhead, and gcov adds a ton of overhead. Using both at once multiplies the overhead. I would suggest only using gcov for those times when you actually need code coverage results (and get those results running *outside of valgrind*).

Comment: I agree with both of the above comments. I guess my question is specifically: why does it sometime take ~100 milliseconds for some tests... and then take over 80 seconds for others? The difference is so huge, there must be something to explain the discrepancy.

Comment: How could we know that without seeing the tests in question?

Comment: One reason for the difference could be in the amount of dynamically allocated memory in the different tests.   Roughly, the more memory your program is using, the more book-keeping valgrind has to do.

Comment: I have unit tests that show ~100x slowdown when using gcov (w/o valgrind). I realize gcov comes with some overhead, but 100x is pretty excessive and indicates "something" is unreasonably slow.

Answer (score 3):

If you're disappointed by valgrind's performance, you can try the fledgling AddressSanitizer from Google. http://blog.chromium.org/2011/06/testing-chromium-addresssanitizer-fast.html  It requires recompiling your code with a special compiler, but no source-level changes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

One potential reason is mentioned here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.gcc.help/aS3mQGzGE_4 - it seems gcov has an O(n^2) step somewhere and is sensitive to long (post-CPP) source lines, or something along these lines.